# Get data from DB before drawing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server

I'm developing application which should connect to MSSQL DB via freetds, get data from db and then show this data. Showing data and getting it from db works fine separately, but when I try to combine them, code which responsible for getting data from db always run after code which should draw this data. May be somebody explain where I`m wrong.

KSOAppDelegate.m

```
#import "KSOAppDelegate.h"
#import "KSOCharViewController.h"

@implementation KSOAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    KSOCharViewController *cvc = [[KSOCharViewController alloc]init];

    self.window.rootViewController = cvc;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

KSOCharViewController.m

```
#import "KSOCharViewController.h"
#import "KSOChartView.h"

@implementation KSOCharViewController
-(void)loadView
{
    KSOChartView *mainView = [[KSOChartView alloc]init];
    self.view = mainView;
}
```

KSOChartView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
    client.delegate = self;
    [client connect:@"10.146.1.28:1433" username:@"sa" password:@"password" database:@"Intraservice4" completion:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success)
                {
                        [client execute:@"SELECT u.Name,count(t.Id) as tot FROM [Intraservice4].[dbo].[Task] t left join TaskExecutor te on t.id = te.TaskId left join [User] u on te.UserId = u.id where 1=1 and StatusId not in ( 28,29,30,53) group by u.Name order by u.Name" completion:^(NSArray* results) {
                                //NSLog(@"%@",[results[0][0] valueForKey:@"tot"]);
                NSLog(@"THIS SHOULD BE THE FIRST BUT ITS NOT!!!!");
                //[self process:results];
                [client disconnect];
                        }];
                }
        }];

       NSLog(@"THIS SHOUD BE THE SECOND BUT ITS NOT");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log `NSLog(@"THIS SHOUD BE THE SECOND BUT ITS NOT");` is outside of the completion block, so it will run immediately after you call `connect:username:password:database:completion:`, because that method is not blocking (it returns immediately and calls `completion` when the asynchronous operation is complete).

So, you need to move your 'second' logic into the `completion` block, or, preferably, call a method from the block which runs your 'second' logic.

Comment: Wain, you mean create new method for getting data from DB and call it from drawRect method before my "second" logic?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice you were doing this from `drawRect:` - stop that now! Move all of this to a different method, and create a new method for the `second` set of logic. Trigger the method call from something other than `drawRect:` - which is to be used only for drawing...

Comment: Why is this code in the view instead of the controller? It should be in the controller.